# File deletion inconsistent when running app through xode

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been making a simple voice recorder app and I've noticed a little glitch when transitioning from running the app on my iphone through xcode.  When I run the app on its own (not through xcode) and record 10 tracks and then connect the app through xcode on my iphone, I can see my recorded 10 tracks in my apps `tableview` and directory folder.

I then go ahead and delete a few tracks while still running on xcode.  Each time I delete I print out the contents of the directory holding the tracks and make sure the tracks are deleted and reload my `tableview` where the deleted tracks no longer appear.  If I then stop xcode and run the app on its own again, the deleted tracks appear in the apps `tableview`, but they've definitely been deleted.  I verify they're deleted by checking out the directory of the app where the content is stored.

Is this type of behavior normal when transitioning between running the app on its and xcode?   I can't replicate the problem when running the app completely on its own.

Comment: I would recommend refreshing the table view when you are disconnected from Xcode to see if it is just a caching issue.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam what do you mean by refreshing the tableview when disconnected?

Comment: You can add a refresh control to the table view that reloads the data when you pull up on the table view, or do it automatically when the view loads. I just think that your problem may be caching on the iPhone's end as there is no other reason the files would still show up in the table view.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam I have `viewDidAppear` in my view controller that contains the tableview. Within `viewDidAppear` I call `reloadData`.  That should do it, right?

Comment: Yes, that should refresh the table view. If that doesn't work, I would suggest posting your table view data source code to see if there is a problem there.